# Camel RouteTemplate ignoring noAutoStartup()

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to use .noAutoStartup() with RouteTemplate feature in Camel but it seems to ignore it?

```
   .templateParameter("encoding")
            .templateParameter("enquireLinkTimer")
            .from("smpp://{{systemId}}@{{host}}:{{port}}?password={{password}}&systemType={{systemType}}&sourceAddrTon={{sourceAddrTon}}&sourceAddrNpi={{sourceAddrNpi}}&destAddrTon={{destAddrTon}}&destAddrNpi={{destAddrNpi}}&dataCoding={{dataCoding}}&alphabet={{alphabet}}&encoding={{encoding}}&enquireLinkTimer={{enquireLinkTimer}}")
            .noAutoStartup()
            //.autoStartup("false")
            .doTry()
```

It seems like RouteTemplateDefinition in `public RouteDefinition asRouteDefinition()` does not copy autoStartup settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet supported, you are welcome to create a JIRA ticket about this at the Apache Camel project

Comment: I have created an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16165